# Conditionally intercept a mouse click in Autohotkey?

Tags: toggle, mouseevent, autohotkey, intercept

I want to have a script which will intercept a mouse click and send a key press instead, but only when the capslock key is toggled on. I want the mouse click to be sent normally if the capslock key is toggled off.

Currently I have made this:

```
$LButton::
if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 1
    send, {a}
else
    send, {LButton}
return
```

The problem with this is that when the capslock key is off, the left button can click perfectly normally but it cannot drag.

If I change `$` to `~`, it is able to drag but it also performs a click when the capslock key is toggled on.

Is there any way to make the script ignore the click completely if the capslock key is toggled off?

Comment: Good question. +1  Wish I knew what to tell you.  Well, in your current script, if capslock is OFF, it sends a left-click because that's what you are telling it to do.  If you want it to ignore the left click, then don't send `LButton`, - I think I'm missing your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AHK_L's `#If` will give you what you want:

```
#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
LButton::Send, a
```

With this code, you won't have to bother what happens when capslock is off. AHK will intercept the click on a lower level and let it trickle through.

Answer (score 0):

How to use the symbol [UP](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#keyup).

```
SetBatchLines, -1   ; you pretty much have to include this to speed up the execution

LButton::
    if( GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") )
        tooltip, ignore left click
    else
        send, {LButton Down}
return


LButton UP::
    send, {LButton Up}
return
```